# cutting a hole in cube with subdivision surface modifier already applied

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to cut a rectangular hole in my cube. You can download my source file on this [link](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36942). The cube was tempered with subdivision modifier and the shading is smooth. This is what I got so far:

[image]

I used the left block and a boolean modifier to cut a hole. The problem is that I need my hole to be exactly the same shape as block-right angles are necessity. The Blender gives a warning that my boolean modifier is not the first one and that results may not be what I expect. So how do I cut a block hole out of the object with smooth surface? This really bugs me and I'm very thankful for your help.

EDIT: situation after smoothing inner part of cube with subdivision modifier and Smooth option from Shading panel:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first. Boolean is not a good choice in my opinion to receive simple shapes like that.

If I understand you right, you only want a cube which has rounden edges with a rectangular whole in the middle.

This is how I would do it.
First create a simple Cube.

[image]

Than subdivide it twice

[image]

Delete the inner faces

[image]

Now select "Bridge Edge Loop" under the "CTRL +E" Sub Menu

[image]

Last but not least, round your edges

[image]

Now you can still add a subdivision Modifier to make it even more smooth.

[image]

To keep the whole sharp, select all edges and increase the Mean Crease to 1.

[image]

Now select the faces you want to be sharp and click Faces -> Sharp under the "Shading"-Tab

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to add subdivision modifier only to outer edges? I want the inner part to be a rectangle

Comment: @krompir2 yes you can, hang on I will update my answer

Comment: beautiful! I wanted to add additional smoothness so I clicked Smooth from Shading panel. Unfortunately, the whole cube gets smooth. Is it possible to apply Smooth only to outer edges?

Comment: @krompir2 yes it is, I will update again :D

Comment: Man, I love you :D

Comment: This is my last question, I promise! After smoothing everything except faces I wanted to be sharp I got this funny looking edges of the hole(I eddited my question with picture). Can this be avoided?

Comment: try selecting the faces next to the whole and set them to flat shading as well

Comment: It worked, thank you again!  For future projects I would like to hire a capable 3D artists and you fit the profile perfectly. Do you have a business card(webpage) so I can contact you someday?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25621/discussion-between-slim-marten-and-krompir2).

Comment: Since my reputation is too low I can't really chat. Thank you for your help.

Comment: oh didn't notice, sorry. Maybe jsut check out my companies website. (http://www.weareslim.de).

We also make 3D Projects. Here's one of our experimental webgl projects (http://ninjadash.weareslim.de)

Comment: great stuff. thx for the info